# 250 / 500 threads limit in GmailApp with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I noticed the following limitation when using `GmailApp` in Google Apps Script:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search("to:test@example.com");
Logger.log(threads.length);  // 250 max

var threads = GmailApp.search("label:mylabel");
Logger.log(threads.length);  // 500 max

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('mylabel');
var threads2 = label.getThreads();
Logger.log(threads2.length); // 500 max
```

**How would you make a job** (such as extracting email adresses and adding them to a list) **on more than 500 or 250 threads?**

Would you do it manually by splitting by dates (not very beautiful but probably working)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could loop over the result with a `max` of e.g. 100 and stop when the length of the resulting `threads` is less than `max`:

```
var max = 100;
var offset = 0;
var searchThreads = [];

while (true) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:test@example.com", offset, max);
  searchThreads = searchThreads.concat(threads);
  if (threads.length < max) {
    break;
  }

  offset += max;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I double-checked and I made my previous test ... on a label which had *exactly* 250 threads, so it was confusing! Such a luck! Now tested with a 600+ threads label and your code works!

Comment: @Basj Haha, that's unfortunate. Glad you figured it out.